# How to find the list of Secondary owner of all users OneDrive for Business using CSOM and PNP Online

Tags: onedrive-for-business

How to get the list of Secondary owner of all users OneDrive for Business using CSOM and PNP Online.

Comment: you can use the logic from [here](https://www.jijitechnologies.com/blogs/add-remove-secondary-site-collection-admin-to-all-onedrive-for-business-users)